# Data can't be saved in my Database when the content is not english

Tags: php, mysql, lang

I have a project that I am creating. I can save data in my database if it is written in English but in another language like my native language Tagalog, it won't save. I used PHP and MySql on this project. Here is the structure of my database
[image: Database]

My code works perfectly fine. I try to input some english words and it worked!

Comment: Structure looks fine, the issue is likely in your code. Google "UTF-8 all the way PHP" for broader articles about this. Somewhere along the way you are not correctly using unicode/UTF-8.

Comment: Are you able to insert Tagalog content through phpmyadmin ?

Comment: What do you mean it won't save? Show us the `INSERT` query along with the values that you want to insert and if it won't save, would it have any error message?

Comment: Also please replace the photo with textual table structure info. Just run `SHOW CREATE TABLE poems` and paste the result [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67996070/edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to change collation to whatever fits your language. Try utf8_general_ci